# best_in_place is not a function error in Rails 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, inplace-editing, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place gem for my Rails 3.2.1 application. I have no error in my development. When I try to run the application in production, I am getting a script error

```
$(".best_in_place").best_in_place is not a function in my browser.
```

In my view page, I have the following code

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "best_inplace", "jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery.dataTables.min" %>


<%= best_in_place @user, :description, :type => :textarea %>

<script>
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
</script>
```

Comment: stylesheet_link_tag `best_inplace` missing an underscore `_place`

Comment: no..its correct. this is the stylesheet I am using.

Comment: You'll need to show us your application.js. The question here is really, "why isn't `best_in_place` being included in my page?"

Answer (score 4):

Me too had this problem some mins ago, solved by moving the `require best_in_place` to the end, other places won't work. Weird but works anyway.

This is the `application.js` manifest

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require_tree .
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
//= require best_in_place

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
})
```

Comment: Yes its true, I have also encountered this situation earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function `best_in_place()?` is declared inside `best_in_pace.js`, which might still need to be loaded while the code in `application.js` calling `best_in_place()` is executed. The proper solution is to enable concatenation of js files through the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). This can be done by including

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

and/or removing

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

in `config/environments/development.rb` resp. `config/environments/production.rb`. Then, 
the place where `best_in_pace.js` is included does not matter (as long as it comes after `jquery.js` and before the code calling `best_in_place()`).